# simple non db technique to display a changeable message to users from Heroku server

Tags: node.js, heroku

Long time reader, first time question asker, please be gentle.

I'm after a simple technique to display a simple message to users that I can easily edit and change.  Stored on the server so when the client connects they will get the latest message.  I'm using Heroku with a simple node.js server.

I'd rather not store it in a database (mongo etc) as this is overkill and I'm not using a db for any other reason.

I don't want to store it in the server code as this seems a bit cumbersome to redeploy the server to Heroku whenever the message changes.

Maybe it's Monday morning and my wife has swapped my coffee for decafe but any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Store a JSON file in a connected AWS directory. Pass in, in the configuration, where the file is so it's not hardwired.

Comment: ... or put a message in Settings > Config Vars. That would probably make it easiest to incorporate and probably edit, but that depends on the message itself and whether you'd have to respawn your containers after editing the message.

Comment: Did you go back to bed?

Comment: Thanks Jared, exactly what I was looking for.  Had to mow the lawns given it's the first sunny day for a while.